# Linkki-Tables: How do I display a text in multiple lines inside a cell?

Tags: linkki

For example in the following table I want to display the whole address in a single cell.

| Row | Address |
| --- | --- |
| row 1 | Friedenheimer Bruecke 21 |
|  | 80639 Munich |
| row 2 | row |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use @UILabel as component type for your address column and set the annotation property `htmlContent = true`.

For example:

```
@UILabel(position = 10, htmlContent = true)
public String getAddress() {
    return "Friedenheimer Brücke 21</br>80639 München";
}
```